# Javascript form validation not working through LightCMS

Tags: javascript, forms, content-management-system

So I'm pasting in some code for a form from Salesforce.

This code to be specific: **(from the style element to the end of the form)** https://gist.github.com/13ab0efd07c2c8cdb3e1

When clicking submit while not filling out any or all fields, I get a form validation check and then a message will popup with the fields that I have not filled out.

However, when I paste the code into our LightCMS template the form validation is not working and just redirects to the thankyou page as if everything went through fine.

They use LightCMS. And even when link to an external js file instead of embedding the js I still get the same results.

I've noticed it adds an "onclick" element on the Submit button on the front-end but it only does that when it's in the CMS not on a bare bones HTML page.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add this

```
onsubmit=return formvalidator(Document.getElementByid(search-form))
```

before form action because it will check the form before submitting it. if check fails the action will not occur.

Comment: 1 more thing the form validator is checking for only empty fields but is should also check their format.

Comment: Did you mean before the <form> element or before the action attribute? For example: 

<form target="_top" method="POST" onsubmit=return formvalidator(Document.getElementByid(search_form)) action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" id="search_form" name="search_form">